# Не отображаются кнопки, созданные в шаблоне

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Всем привет. Сразу скажу я абсолютный новичок - поэтому не судите строго) В моем шаблоне есть проверка: соответствует ли пользователь и автор комментария. Если да, то у него должно быть право отредактировать/удалить комментарий, который он оставлял под постом моей "соцсети". Но эти кнопки не отображаются даже без условия. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что может быть не так.

```
    {% if user == comment.author %}
      <a class="btn btn-sm text-muted" href="{% url 'blog:edit_comment' post.id comment.id %}" role="button">
        Отредактировать комментарий
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-sm text-muted" href="{% url 'blog:delete_comment' post.id comment.id %}" role="button">
        Удалить комментарий
      </a>
    {% endif %}
```

```
path('posts/<int:pk>/edit_comment/<comment_id>/',
         views.edit_comment, name='edit_comment'),
```

```
@login_required
def edit_comment(request, pk, comment_id):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    if comment.author != request.user:
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', pk)
    form = CommentForm(
        request.POST or None,
        files=request.FILES or None,
        instance=comment)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('blog:post_detail', pk=pk)
    template = 'blog/create.html'
    context = {'form': form,
               'comment': comment}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас в переменной `context` не передаётся `user`.